# Airflow Scheduler on Webserver: "The scheduler does not appear to be running" after installation

Tags: airflow, mysql-connector

I have installed Airflow 2.2.5 in my local VM (Oracle Virtual Box 8.6) with MySQL 8.0 as database backend and went through the installation process shown in the website (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation/index.html).

I am using the 'sql_alchemy_conn' argument below:

> mysql+mysqlconnector://airflow_user:airflow_password@localhost:3306/airflow_db

I managed to install Airflow, its dependencies (at least what has been asked throughout the process) and got to a point where I can log in to the webserver. However the webserver says the scheduler is not running, as show in the picture:
[image: Scheduler error in webserver]

When I execute "airflow scheduler" in the terminal, I get the following error:

```
[2022-09-14 15:43:28,943] {authentication.py:59} INFO - package: mysql.connector.plugins
[2022-09-14 15:43:28,947] {authentication.py:60} INFO - plugin_name: mysql_native_password
[2022-09-14 15:43:28,953] {authentication.py:64} INFO - AUTHENTICATION_PLUGIN_CLASS: MySQLNativePasswordAuthPlugin
  ____________       _____________
 ____    |__( )_________  __/__  /________      __
____  /| |_  /__  ___/_  /_ __  /_  __ \_ | /| / /
___  ___ |  / _  /   _  __/ _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ /
 _/_/  |_/_/  /_/    /_/    /_/  \____/____/|__/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 398, in _process_params_dict
    conv = to_mysql(conv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/conversion.py", line 194, in to_mysql
    ) from None
TypeError: Python 'taskinstancestate' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1277, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 608, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 541, in execute
    stmt = _bytestr_format_dict(stmt, self._process_params_dict(params))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 406, in _process_params_dict
    ) from err
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing pyformat-parameters; Python 'taskinstancestate' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 48, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 48, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 92, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/scheduler_command.py", line 75, in scheduler
    _run_scheduler_job(args=args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/scheduler_command.py", line 46, in _run_scheduler_job
    job.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs/base_job.py", line 242, in run
    session.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1046, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 504, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 483, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2540, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2682, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2642, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 422, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 589, in execute
    uow,
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 245, in save_obj
    insert,
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1136, in _emit_insert_statements
    statement, params
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1011, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 298, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1130, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1317, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1511, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1277, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 608, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 541, in execute
    stmt = _bytestr_format_dict(stmt, self._process_params_dict(params))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 406, in _process_params_dict
    ) from err
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) Failed processing pyformat-parameters; Python 'taskinstancestate' cannot be converted to a MySQL type
[SQL: INSERT INTO job (dag_id, state, job_type, start_date, end_date, latest_heartbeat, executor_class, hostname, unixname) VALUES (%(dag_id)s, %(state)s, %(job_type)s, %(start_date)s, %(end_date)s, %(latest_heartbeat)s, %(executor_class)s, %(hostname)s, %(unixname)s)]
[parameters: {'dag_id': None, 'state': <TaskInstanceState.RUNNING: 'running'>, 'job_type': 'SchedulerJob', 'start_date': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 14, 18, 43, 29, 247880), 'end_date': None, 'latest_heartbeat': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 14, 18, 43, 29, 247894), 'executor_class': 'LocalExecutor', 'hostname': 'airhost', 'unixname': 'root'}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)
```

I have been clueless about this section:

```
"msql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing pyformat-parameters; Python 'taskinstancestate' cannot be converted to a MySQL type".
```

What does that mean? Any ideas? I haven't run any DAGs or built anything so far.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this. The problem was related to the driver mysqlconnector chosen for 'sql_alchemy_conn' string. I switched to pymysql and the problem was solved:

```
mysql+pymysql://airflow_user:airflow_password@localhost:3306/airflow_db
```